# How many degrees does the parent node need to rotate along point A to make the CD point at the given point (x, y)

Tags: unity-game-engine

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbRH3.png)
A is the parent node, AB is a straight line, CD is an object on the parent node, and the direction is CD. Now, click a point (x, y) anywhere on the screen with the mouse,

May I ask: How many degrees does the parent node need to rotate along point A to make the CD point at the given point (x, y)? How can I calculate the rotation angle of A?

I have tried many methods, but there is no good calculation method. Does anyone know how to conveniently calculate the rotation angle of A? Thank you!

I am using the Unity engine and have been trying to calculate such a rotation angle for a long time, but there is no convenient way. I know this can be calculated, but I have not found a suitable method. My own calculation method is too cumbersome, which is not conducive to finding the final angle.

Comment: I don't understand this question at all. The image appears to depict a line segment CD. The description state that CD is some sort of "object", "on" the parent node A (but the image shows no such relation with point A). Next, CD is described as a "point".

Comment: The question makes no sense as asked. Can you try rephrasing? Or can someone with knowledge of your problem and more familiarity with English to help you reword it for us?

Comment: First, raycast into the scene from the mouse to get the point the node needs to look at.  There are many tutorials online for this.  And then use Transform.LookAt to make it look at it.   There is no need to calulate the angle, and if you really do want the angle, you can get it from the resulting transform.